# Adding variables to args[] on command line

Tags: java

I'm learning Java with Head First's Java book and this code came across.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;


public class MiniMiniMusicCmdLine {   

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MiniMiniMusicCmdLine mini = new MiniMiniMusicCmdLine();
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Don't forget the instrument and note args");
    } else {
        int instrument = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int note = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        mini.play(instrument, note);

    }
 }

public void play(int instrument, int note) {

  try {

     Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();         
     player.open();

     Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);         
     Track track = seq.createTrack();  

     MidiEvent event = null;

     ShortMessage first = new ShortMessage();
     first.setMessage(192, 1, instrument, 0);
     MidiEvent changeInstrument = new MidiEvent(first, 1); 
     track.add(changeInstrument);


     ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
     a.setMessage(144, 1, note, 100);
     MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1); 
     track.add(noteOn);

     ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
     b.setMessage(128, 1, note, 100);
     MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16); 
     track.add(noteOff);
     player.setSequence(seq); 
     player.start();
     // new
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     player.close();
     System.exit(0);

  } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

I tried to run it on IntelliJ and command line but the output is always the same. The program always prints "Don't forget the instrument and note args" and executes itself. Am I doing something wrong or did things changed in Java since this book published?

Comment: How did you run this on commandline? The command?

Comment: Man i just figured it out. So I have to type the variables too when i launch the program on the command line. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You actually have to supply the arguments when running

Comment: @monteroyale Exactly. Can you mark the single answer down as accepted? If it doesnt have enough information, post one yourself and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

command line

`java MiniMiniMusicCmdLine  1 2`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments to args[] on command line simply use:

`java MiniMiniMusicCmdLine ABCD PQRS`

Answer (score -1):

To Run a Java Program with Command arguments in Command Line you must compile as usual as,

**`javac MiniMiniMusicCmdLine`**

And to Pass arguments in Command Line

```
java file_name parameter1 parameter2
```

> `java MiniMiniMusicCmdLine 1 2`

Comment: You can't compile this way. Javac will throw error.

Comment: @xenteros can you state whats the Error